# How to collect filenames from a list of file names with each length of the file into n-second parts - leetcode like question

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

> Given a list of list of filenames with its corresponding length of file:
> (The file is a list of audio data and varies in the number of seconds thus size)
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> filename_and_len = [["file1", 6], ["file2, 4], ["file3", 9], ["file4", 7]]
> ```
>
> and n is the desired number of seconds you want to split each clip into so we output the list of file names for each n-second clip such as the following when n=5:
>
> ```
> ["file1", "file1_file2", "file3", "file3_file4", "file4"]
> ```
>
> Assume that n is already a number that is divisible by the total number of seconds across the files.

The following is the code that I have so far:

```
filename_and_len = [["file1", 6], ["file2", 4], ["file3", 9], ["file4", 7]]

n_temp = n
final_file_names = []
while n_temp < n:
    for i in range(len(filename_and_len)):
        if filename_and_len[i][1] > n: 
            final_file_names[i] = filename_and_len[i][0]
            n_temp =  n_temp + n
        elif filename_and_len[i][1] < n: 
            final_file_names[i] = filename_and_len[i][0]
            i++
```

I haven't completed this code but I was wondering if this is kind of the right direction?

Comment: `i++` is not syntactically valid and even if it were, `i` would be immediately overwritten. Plus your code has other problems, like `n_temp = n ... while n_temp < n` and `final_file_names[i] = ...`. So what are you really asking? Do you want an idea of what the algorithm should look like, without the implementation? Cause that's not really what SO is meant for. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341)

Comment: To be clear, the recommended way to ask a question about homework is to **try doing it yourself**, but then ask a question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import itertools as it

filename_and_len = [["file1", 6], ["file2", 4], ["file3", 9], ["file4", 7]]

filenames, lengths = zip(*filename_and_len)

# Get two iterables of the `filenames` variable
nameiters = it.tee(filenames, 2)

# Advance the second iterator one position
next(nameiters[1])

# Zip up the iterators and join element together with an "_" character
namejoins = map("_".join, zip(*nameiters)))

# Now zip the filenames into the joined names and flatten with a chain
chained = it.chain(*zip(filenames, namejoins))

# Now slice N from the chain
sliced = it.islice(chained, N)

# Collect into a `list` and print.
print(list(sliced))
```